# Using singletons to pass data between views

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have a mapView that drops annotations, and the annotations have callouts that pushes a new view to the stack. In the second view, users input text and takes a picture that appears on the view and I want it to be saved once I press the save button. But there will be multiple annotations on the map and I want the data on the second view to be different for each annotation. I was told to use a singleton to do this, and I know how to make one, but I do not know how to make it pass or store the data. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: It's not clear why you need a singleton based on this description.  Is the annotation data stored in the class that implements MKAnnotation?  You seem to have multiple questions here.  Have you gotten the second view to show each annotation's different data at least?  If not, figure that out before trying to "save changes".  These may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939223/store-data-in-mkannotation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797047/how-to-keep-data-associated-with-mkannotation-from-being-lost-after-a-callout-po, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11834582/467105.

Comment: Ok I actually have a different idea, so I am not implementing this anymore. Thanks for the help though.